# select between two values with two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello guys I'm a bit stumped on this one, hopefully someone can lend me a hand.
I have a table like such.

```
CREATE TABLE ACCT (ACCT_FROM VARCHAR2(6) , ACCT_TO VARCHAR2(6) );
```

with these values

```
INSERT INTO ACCT VALUES ('2015', '2018');  
INSERT INTO ACCT VALUES ('2019');  
INSERT INTO ACCT (ACCT_FROM) VALUES ('2019');  

"ACCT_FROM" "ACCT_TO"
"2015"  "2018"
"2019"  ""
```

I'm trying to select a query that would essentially give me the from and to values in between where the account  starts with 2. This is just a subset of a much larger table. So i would like to end up with something like

```
ACCT
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
```

I have tried something like below but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
select acct_from  from ACCT where   
acct_from between '2000' and '2999'  
and (ACCT_FROM like '2%' or ACCT_TO like '2%') ;
```

Can someone help me get the appropriate result.

Thanks.

Comment: So - are all your values four-digit numbers, some possibly like 1996 and others that start with 2? And you want to find the smallest that starts with 2, the largest that starts with 2, and then fill the gaps all in one column? WHICH numbers should be considered - all the numbers from both columns of the input table, considered together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *seem* to want something like this. It is a strange requirement; perhaps you used "years" just for illustration, but if they really are years, what if a row has ACCT_FROM = 1997, ACCT_TO = 2003? Shouldn't the result set include 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003?

Anyway - the solution below answers what you requested; not what you may have meant to request. If this is not what you need, please clarify.

```
with
     acct ( acct_from, acct_to ) as (
       select '2015', '2018' from dual union all
       select '2019', null   from dual
     ),
     prep ( acct_2xxx ) as (
       select  to_number(acct_from)
         from  acct
         where acct_from like '2%'
       union all
       select  to_number(acct_to)
         from  acct
         where acct_to like '2%'
     ),
     acct_m ( acct_min, acct_max ) as (
       select min(acct_2xxx), max(acct_2xxx)
       from   prep
     )
select to_char(acct_min + level - 1) as acct_all
from   acct_m
connect by level <= acct_max - acct_min + 1
;

ACCT_ALL
----------------
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019

5 rows selected.
```

NOTE - I also assumed you didn't seriously mean to use the same name (ACCT) for a table and for a column in another table. I didn't follow your lead with that.

Comment: They are actually account codes 4 digits. Thanks for the response I gave my dll and my inserts as a way to show you exactly what I was dealing with. This is not a table i have control over. Is part of a software that my company bought, hence my conversion to a number. Thanks for the response I appreciated.

Comment: @Miguel - understood, but you do have control over the name of the column in the result set (or don't you?) So you could choose not to call it ACCT. More importantly - is that what you needed, or something else? I am thinking of two rows in the input, 2003 - 2008 and 2033 - 2036. Do you need all the numbers from 2003 to 2008 and from 2033 to 2036, or ALL the numbers from 2003 to 2036? My solution does the latter (ALL the numbers) - is that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

I have a nice one for you. I made some assumptions: the data in your varchar coloumn are numbers. Or to be exactly year-numbers. So whats happening

```
with nrs as ( select rownum  +1999 nr from ( select 1 from dual group by cube (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ) where rownum <= 1000 )
```

is generating numbers from 2000 to 2999

The first part of the union uses this to show all the numbers between acct_to and acct_from but only the numbers from the "nr generator".

The second part of the union adds all the nrs between 2000 and 2999 where acct_from is null.

The union makes you lose all the duplicates.

```
with nrs as ( select rownum  +1999 nr from ( select 1 from dual group by cube (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ) where rownum <= 1000 )
select nrs.nr 
from   acct 
,      nrs
where  acct_to is not null
and    nrs.nr between to_number( acct_from ) and to_number( acct_to )
union 
select to_number(acct_from )
from   acct 
where  acct_to is null 
and    to_number(acct_from) between 2000 and 2999
```

;

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you are looking for this :

```
SELECT Val 
FROM
(
    SELECT ACCT_FROM AS Val FROM ACCT WHERE ACCT_FROM like '2%' 
    UNION
    SELECT ACCT_TO AS Val FROM ACCT  WHERE ACCT_TO like '2%' 
) T
ORDER BY Val
```

Change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` if you want to keep the duplicates

Comment: Ah i get it now... you want to create the missing values. For numbers thats feasible but your column is declared varchar. So what kind of values do you have in there? Going to bed now. I'look at this tomorrow if nobody answered

Answer (score 0):

ok I have the answer. Hopefully this helps someone else.

```
with rangeOfAccounts(accounts, acct_to) as (
    select to_number(acct_from) as accounts,  to_number(ACCT_TO) as acct_to
    from acct where acct_from like '2%'
    union all
    select accounts + 1, ACCT_TO
    from rangeOfAccounts
    where accounts + 1 <= ACCT_TO
)
select accounts
from rangeOfAccounts
order by accounts
```